# Ruby gems issue (whats going on)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am a bit confused over what is happening. I have my application using a few different gems and for some reason there is a problem requiring any more gems. So for example. I have this in config/environment.rb

```
config.gem 'will_paginate', :version => '2.3.12'
config.gem "bandsintown"
config.gem "gchartrb"
```

I just added **gchartrb**. When i run

```
 rake gems
(in /Users/matt/Sites/someapp)
  - [R] will_paginate = 2.3.12
  - [R] bandsintown 
  - [ ] gchartrb 

 I = Installed
 F = Frozen
 R = Framework (loaded before rails starts)
```

then i run

```
sudo rake gems:install

gem install gchartrb
Successfully installed gchartrb-0.8
1 gem installed

gem list | grep gchart
gchartrb (0.8)
```

So I am confused on what to do. I am on snow leopard on mac osx. Here is my environment

```
which gem
 /usr/local/bin/gem
which ruby
 /usr/local/bin/ruby

gem env

RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin10.4.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /Users/matt/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
     - :sources => ["http://gems.rubyforge.org/", "http://gems.github.com", "http://gemcutter.org"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
     - http://gems.github.com
     - http://gemcutter.org
```

If anyone has any clue to why I cant seem to install any other gems into this application...

here is my error

```
script/server 
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.8 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
Missing these required gems:
  gchartrb  

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.7.174 at /usr/local/bin/ruby
  rubygems 1.3.7 at /Users/matt/.gem/ruby/1.8, /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

Comment: Well, you *install* gems to your computer, then *load* them in your application. You can have many gems installed, but only load some for any given app. Can you confirm via `gem list` whether or not the gem installed? That way, we can know whether it's an issue in installing or loading.

Comment: if you look at my question i have the output of gem list and its present

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that `gchartrb` is the name of the gem, but you need to require `google_chart` to load the gem. Try this instead

```
config.gem "gchartrb", :lib => "google_chart"
```